# Pulling the next value in a table

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to flatten a table to pull out phone numbers, but I'm having a bit of difficulty. The code below works fine when there is no repetition of the TypeID but as soon as there is it returns the same telephone number. Is there a way I can pull out the next phone number that hasn't already been pulled out?

Query

```
SELECT debtorid,
MAX( DECODE( TypeID , 1 , TELNO) ) AS Phone1 ,
MAX( DECODE( TypeID , 2 , TELNO ) ) AS Phone2 ,
MAX( DECODE( TypeID , 3 , TELNO ) ) AS Phone3 ,
MAX( DECODE( TypeID , 4 , TELNO ) ) AS Phone4,
MAX( DECODE( TypeID , 4 , TELNO ) ) AS Phone5
FROM PUB."DebtorTelNo"
where "DebtorTELNO"."DebtorId" = '123123' and "Superseded" = 0
GROUP BY DebtorId
```

Table

```
DebtorID   TelNo         Superseded  TelPTR  TYPEID
 123123    07920155555      0          1       1
 123123    01732XXXXXX      0          6       2
 123123    0161XXXXXXX      0          7       3
 123123    0171XXXXXXX      0         12       4
 123123    0181XXXXXXX      0         15       4 
 123123    0191xxxxxxx      0         17       4
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do in the end? It looks to me that what you're doing now is inherently flawed because what if someone has 6 phone numbers or more?

If you just want to put all the phone numbers in one row and you don't need a separate field for each I would suggest using something like [stragg](http://www.sqlsnippets.com/en/topic-11591.html). If you define this function you can do something like this:

```
select debtorid, stragg(TELNO) as TelList 
where "DebtorTELNO"."DebtorId" = '123123' and "Superseded" = 0
group by debtorid
```

and this would give you something like:

```
DebtorID    TelList
123123      07920155555,01732XXXXXX,0161XXXXXXX,0171XXXXXXX,0181XXXXXXX,0191xxxxxxx
```

Comment: I don't think stragg works on our database but yes that is what im looking for.

Comment: Sorry I do need a separate field for each number so stragg is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

create a number of subqueries which give you the telno when the type is right and NULL otherwise (pretty much like you did) but also numbers the rows. Something like

```
select rownum r, x.* from (
    select debtorid, decode(typeid,1,telno) phone1 
    from xxx 
    order by debtorid, decode(typeid,1,telno)
)
```

Create one such query for each typeid. Join them all, so the debtorid and r (i.e. the rownum) match.

Now you will have almost what you want, except there are some rows where all columns are null. Filter these out.

So you end up with something like

```
select a.debtorid, phone1, phone2, phone3, phone4 from
(select rownum r, x.* from (select debtorid, decode(typeid,1,telno) phone1 from xxx order by debtorid, decode(typeid,1,telno)) x) a,
(select rownum r, x.* from (select debtorid, decode(typeid,2,telno) phone2 from xxx order by debtorid, decode(typeid,2,telno)) x) b,
(select rownum r, x.* from (select debtorid, decode(typeid,3,telno) phone3 from xxx order by debtorid, decode(typeid,3,telno)) x) c,
(select rownum r, x.* from (select debtorid, decode(typeid,4,telno) phone4 from xxx order by debtorid, decode(typeid,4,telno)) x) d
where 
    a.debtorid = b.debtorid
and b.debtorid = c.debtorid
and c.debtorid = d.debtorid
and a.r = b.r
and b.r = c.r
and c.r = d.r
and phone1||phone2||phone3||phone4 is not null
;
```

With your data this returns:

```
Debtorid|phone1     |phone2     |phone3     |phone4     |
---------------------------------------------------------
  123123|07920155555|01732XXXXXX|0161XXXXXXX|0171XXXXXXX|
  123123|           |           |           |0181XXXXXXX|
  123123|           |           |           |0191xxxxxxx|
```

Adding another telno also looks okay

```
0:opal@spmdtz> insert into xxx values (123123, 'new1',2);

Debtorid|phone1     |phone2     |phone3     |phone4     |
---------------------------------------------------------
  123123|07920155555|01732XXXXXX|0161XXXXXXX|0171XXXXXXX|
  123123|           |new1       |           |0181XXXXXXX|
  123123|           |           |           |0191xxxxxxx|
```

And so does adding another debtor id

```
0:opal@spmdtz> insert into xxx values (123124, 'new2',2);

Debtorid|phone1     |phone2     |phone3     |phone4     |
---------------------------------------------------------
  123123|07920155555|01732XXXXXX|0161XXXXXXX|0171XXXXXXX|
  123123|           |new1       |           |0181XXXXXXX|
  123123|           |           |           |0191xxxxxxx|
  123124|           |new2       |           |           |
```

The code may contain a few subtle bugs, but I believe the general idea of numbering rows and joining on matching rownums is probably correct.